# How can i check two tables in the login process

Tags: php, authentication

I have two tables in my database customer and admin i want the login process to check the inputted values and compare it with the admin and customer, if admin open admin page, if customer open customer page

Comment: It is not possible to answer this. We need to know what database you are using, what the tables look like, and exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does your code look like right now? Please check out this article: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show what you have attempted so we know where to start from. But you can achieve your aim like so:

1. You need to check the login details on the admin table.
2. If it returns true then you use the header to redirect the page to the admin page.
3. Else if it returns false then check the login details on the costumer table.
4. If it returns true then you use the header to redirect the page to the costumer page.
5. Else you output an error message.

Hope this helps

Comment: Can u write me an example please, i really need the help for my graduation project

Comment: Am not really good with php,but i have managed to work with it

Comment: I can't write you a blind example. You can upload a screen shot of your admin and customer database table so I know how to help

Comment: I couldn't upload them I'll write to you the fields of the tables, if that's ok

Comment: If you can write them in an understandable way fine. Write it let's see